# Write Blob MetaData and Pages Atomically

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to write data and meta data atomically in azure storage for Page Blobs?

Consider a page blob which has multiple writers.

I see recommendations to use the meta data for things like record count, sequence number, general structure of the blob's data.  However, if two writers write data and then have to update the meta data, isn't there a race where each writes and tries to update the record count by reading the current count and then updating.  Both read 0 and write 1, but there are actually 2.

Same applies to any scenario where the meta data write is not keyed by something particular to that write (eg, each write then writes a ***new*** name-value pair into meta data).

The below suggestion does not seem to work for me.

```
// 512 byte aligned stream with my data
Stream toWrite = PageAlignedStreamManager.Write(data);

long whereToWrite = this.MetaData.TotalWrittenSizeInBytes;
this.MetaData.TotalWrittenSizeInBytes += toWrite.Length;

await this.Blob.FetchAttributesAsync();
if (this.MetaData.TotalWrittenSizeInBytes > this.Blob.Properties.Length)
{
     await this.Blob.ResizeAsync(PageAlignedMemoryStreamManager.PagesRequired(this.MetaData.TotalWrittenSizeInBytes) * PageAlignedMemoryStreamManager.PageSizeBytes * 2);
}

this.MetaData.RevisionNumber++;
this.Blob.Metadata[STREAM_METADATA_KEY] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.MetaData);

// TODO: the below two lines should happen atomically
await this.Blob.WritePagesAsync(toWrite, whereToWrite, null, AccessCondition.GenerateLeaseCondition(this.BlobLeaseId), null, null);
await this.Blob.SetMetadataAsync(AccessCondition.GenerateLeaseCondition(this.BlobLeaseId), null, null);

toWrite.Dispose();
```

If I do not explicitly call SetMetaData as the next action, it does not get set :(

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to write data and meta data atomically in azure storage?

Yes. You could try to update the data and metadata atomically in this way. When we set/update blob metadata using the following code snippet, it is stored in current blob object. Currently, no network call is made.

```
blockBlob.Metadata["docType"] = "textDocuments";
```

when we use the following code to update blob, it actually makes the call to set the blob content and metadata. If upload fails, both blob content and metadata will not be updated.

```
blockBlob.UploadText("new content");
```

> However, if two writers write data and then have to update the meta data, isn't there a race where each writes and tries to update the record count by reading the current count and then updating. Both read 0 and write 1, but there are actually 2.

Azure Storage supports these three data [concurrency strategies](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/managing-concurrency-in-microsoft-azure-storage-2) (Optimistic concurrency, Pessimistic concurrency and Last writer wins), we could use optimistic concurrency control through the **ETag** property, or use pessimistic concurrency control through a **lease**, which could help us guarantee the data consistency.

Comment: Since the SDK is a wrapper over the HTTP REST service, where would I be able to see this behavior?  It would seem that two calls are made when you UploadText, one for meta data and one for data.  I cannot find anything where both are set in docs.  I'll try running the code and capturing network traffic to see if it is actually one call.